# c# chart control update automatically when input changes within few seconds?

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I have a windows form which has few parameters and a chart control which graphs it.
Those few parameters are a track bar, and I made it so that every time one of those track bar value changes, the graph gets updated.

However, I noticed that if I drag the track bar across, the chart drawing suddenly takes a lot of time.

How do I implement the graph so that the graph updates periodically? Say two seconds after application realizes no values are changing?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Timer` control to your form.  Set the `Interval` property to 2000 (2 seconds).  Every time any of the factors that affect the chart change, set the timer's `Enabled` property to true.  In the timer's `Tick` event handler, set the timer's `Enabled` property to false and then update the chart control.